# Looping through object

Tags: javascript, json, oop, object

I am doing an exercise using swapi co API, and after I fetched results from the website but I want to display only some of API objects. For the moment I am struggling with displaying all array spaceships.

```
var linkApi="https://swapi.co/api/starships"
async function starships() 
{
  let response = await fetch(linkApi);
  let data = await response.json()

 for(i=0; i<data.results.length;i++){
  return{

    "count": data.count,
    "results":[
        {
            "name":data.results[i].name,
            "model": data.results[i].model,
            "crew":data.results[i].crew,
        }
    ]

  }
}
  }


starships()
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

this is the format that I want to achive

```
 {
  "count": "",
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "model": "",
      "crew": "",
      "passengers": "",
      "films_count": "",
      "films": [
        {
          "title": "",
          "director": "",
          "release_date": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So you want the director and the release_date of a starship? ;) :D please, relate the expected result from actual data

Comment: Basically, i want to fetch all the data of API in the JSON format presented, but for the moment i am struggling looping through object array.

Answer (score 0):

The return will finish your function returning just the first spaceship info. You should create an object outside the for loop and after the for ends pass it an array with all the spaceships in the format you want

```
var linkApi="https://swapi.co/api/starships"
async function starships() 
{
    let response = await fetch(linkApi);
    let data = await response.json()
    let spaceshipsArray = [];
    let result = {
        "count": data.length
    };
    for(i=0; i < data.results.length;i++){

            spaceshipsArray.push({
            "name":data.results[i].name,
            "model": data.results[i].model,
            "crew":data.results[i].crew,
            });

    }
    }
    result.results = spaceshipsArray;
    return result;
  }
```

It would be something like that.